# how to use Application.OnTime to delay a loop

Tags: vba, timer

SO I'm writing a code which makes references to bloomberg cell formulas... as a result the loop often skips faster than data can load. I think this can be solved relatively easily if I can somehow delay the iteration of the loop ... which would give cells time to populate. This is what I have written so far, and I'm not sure how to write the last line really.

```
x = 1


If x < TixCollection.count Then

    ' runs report if ADR Close is active
    If Sheets("Input").Range("L2").value = "x" Then
        Call build_singleEquity(x)
            'Set pat = New pattern

            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "pattern_recogADR"

            If Sheets("Input").Range("L5").value = "x" Then
                Dim sht_name As String
                sht_name = TixCollection(x).ADR & "_ADRclose"
                Call Sheet_SaveAs(path_ADRclose, sht_name, "SingleEquityHistoryHedge")
            End If
    End If


    'runs report if ORD Close is active
    If Sheets("Input").Range("L9").value = "x" Then
        Call build_ordCloseTrade(x)



            If Sheets("Input").Range("L13").value = "x" Then

                Dim sht_name1 As String
                sht_name1 = TixCollection(x).ADR & "_ORDclose"
                Call Sheet_SaveAs(path_ORDclose, sht_name1, "OrdCloseTrade")
            End If
    End If


Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), x = x + 1 'want to write something like this but syntax is wrong
```

Comment: Worth noting: this code you provide does not actually contain any `Loop` structure.  That aside, I think you need to use the `Sleep` function. See my answer below; try it out, and revise your code as necessary -- if you have trouble I'll check back and try to help.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.OnTime` essentially schedules an event to run at/after a particular time.  It allows you to schedule an event to run even *after* your code has executed and cleared the stack.  This is why it's an `Application` level method.

The `OnTime` method doesn't *pause* or delay anything, it's simply a scheduler.  So the rest of your code will continue to execute, and to whatever extent that code relies on the results of the task that is waiting for the `OnTime`, you'll run in to errors.

In theory, I think you could probably make this approach work in a roundabout way for your purposes, but I think you'd probably be better served to use the WinAPI `Sleep` function.  This also gives you greater granularity (you can specify to the millisecond).

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

You can invoke this from any subroutine or function, by calling:

```
Sleep 5000 'pause for 5000ms, (5 seconds)
```

**UPDATE**

I notice your code doesn't actually contain a `Loop` structure. I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Here's a stab at it:

```
Do While x < TixCollection.count Then  `or consider: Do While x <= TixCollection.Count

    ' runs report if ADR Close is active
    If Sheets("Input").Range("L2").value = "x" Then
        Call build_singleEquity(x)
            'Set pat = New pattern

            Sleep 10000
            Call pattern_recogADR

            If Sheets("Input").Range("L5").value = "x" Then
                Dim sht_name As String
                sht_name = TixCollection(x).ADR & "_ADRclose"
                Call Sheet_SaveAs(path_ADRclose, sht_name, "SingleEquityHistoryHedge")
            End If
    End If


    'runs report if ORD Close is active
    If Sheets("Input").Range("L9").value = "x" Then
        Call build_ordCloseTrade(x)
            If Sheets("Input").Range("L13").value = "x" Then

                Dim sht_name1 As String
                sht_name1 = TixCollection(x).ADR & "_ORDclose"
                Call Sheet_SaveAs(path_ORDclose, sht_name1, "OrdCloseTrade")
            End If
    End If

x = x+1
Sleep 15000  'Wait for 15 seconds  
Loop
```

It is hard to tell if both of the `Sleep` (your previous `OnTime` calls) are really needed, since I'm not sure which one (or if both) was introducing the error condition.

You will need to make sure that you put the code for the `Sleep` function in the vba project.

**Update**

Assuming the sleep function, or `Application.Wait` method does not work for you, one other thing you could try is a simple `Do/While` Loop.  Although I am not able to replicate your condition, this seems like possibly the most reliable.

```
Dim newTime As Date
newTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Do While Not Now >= newTime
    DoEvents
Loop
```

A final option would be to disable and manually force calculation, like below. My understanding is that the application is busy and will not execute code while a calculation event is occurring.  However, with this in mind I'm not sure if any of these approaches will work for you, because although you indicate it's waiting on an Excel worksheet calculation, I don't think that is possible, the worksheet event takes precedence over running code, so I'm thinking that something is still happening on the client side which you might not be able to trap reliably unless they provide some sort of method through the API (something like `.Busy` which returns a boolean, etc.).

```
Dim appCalc as Long: appCalc = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = appCalc  '# disable automatic calculation
Call build_singleEquity(x)
Application.Calculate 'Force calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  '# return to normal/previous property
Call pattern_recogAD
```

Comment: hm ok i'll give that a shot

Comment: hi david the code doesnt work because the sleep function stops everything.. including the cells with bloomberg functions that are loading data

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with bloomberg API but do they provide any method by which you can ascertain whether it is still loading data?  Also, which line(s) in this code are the calls that begin loading data?

Comment: You might also try [`Application.Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx) method.  Not sure if that will work but it should allow for continued recalculation (I'm not sure if your'e actually waiting on a re-calculation of sheet/cells, or some other process).

Comment: The method Call build_SingleEquity creates a collection of tickers and other attributes from an input sheet within the workbook. Those values are then substituted into a shell (ie a separate worksheet with cell reference formulas) which then loads the data. The method Call pattern_recogADR then checks that data to determine different stats which it saves to an array and writes to another sheet. The problem is that pattern_recogADR tries to look at the numbers before bloomberg finishes loading data.

Comment: If you step through this using `F8`, when you reach the line `Call pattern_recogADR`, the previous called procedure can't possibly still be executing; so it seems is the worksheetrecalculating based on formula/cell references, so while `build_singleEquity(x)` has completed, the application is still handling the worksheet recalculation, does that sound about right?

Comment: yeah exactly... so when it gets to pattern_recogADR it throws an error in writing the array because the cells are still calculating

Comment: Application.Wait might work.  Try that. If not, I'm thinking of one more thing.

Comment: where would you suggest i write in application.wait?

Comment: Try using `Application.Wait` instead of `Application.OnTime`, e.g., `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")`.    I put a few other suggestions in my answer above, but ultimately if the API doesn't provide a means of communicating when it's completed doing what it's doing, you might be out of luck.

Comment: hi david... i have posted a simple 2 method version of my code in this thread... you can see what im trying to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964447/implementing-bloomberg-time-delays-with-a-large-amount-of-bdh-cell-references

Comment: You didn't implmenet the `Do While` correctly. You want to use the three lines exactly as I have them in the above answer.  Unfortunately, without access to the Bloomberg API, I'm pretty much out of ideas if these suggestions don't work.  I would suggest reviewing all of the documentation and looking for some method they may expose that would indicate whether their processes have completed, similar to the internetExplorer `.ReadyState` property, etc.

Comment: daivd, im taking a look at my code again, im unclear what i did wrong with my do while loop... i have all three lines in there

Comment: No you don't. YOu have all three lines, but you don't have them in the right place. There should be no other crap in between those lines. You want to force a loop of `DoEvents` until the time has elapsed. As you currently implement it, it's doing the exact opposite: it's doing all of your code without waiting for any time to elapse.

Comment: ok i tried it and it still doesnt work... i think it doesnt load cells while its doing DoEvents. I even tried with more time, like 30 sec. Thanks for your help though, I really appreciate it this is starting to get to me though tbh lol

Comment: Well then you're waiting on some external process -- not simple worksheet calculation.  For this, you really need to rely on their API to provide some method to determine whether it's "finished".  I would be surprised if it does not, or if this is a bug that nobody has discovered, but I don't have access to the program or the documentation.